# Found 1 low severity vulnerability Error, when using React and Serve two files same time

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

The node js gives me the following error. Also When I using ReactJs It renders `App.js` and `index.js` files separately. Which means every function execute twice. I suspect this error responsible for that thing too. Can you any of you help me out to solve the problem.

```sh
   === npm audit security report ===                        


                                       Manual

   Review                                  
               Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

                Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


        Low             Prototype Pollution                                           

        Package         yargs-parser                                                  

        Patched in      >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2              

        Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

        Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > yargs > yargs-parser     

        More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500                             

      found 1 low severity vulnerability in 1668 scanned packages
        1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to explicitly be an error, just an audit report. The vulnerability is in the yargs-parser package (used by the package react-scripts), not in your source code.

Comment: How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an audit report of potential vulnerabilities in your project's dependencies and has nothing to do with your actual project code.

To solve this issue, run try the following:

- `npm audit fix`
- or `npm update`

---

Update: It seems like this issue has not yet been fixed in a released version of the library. Moreover, there are no known mitigation steps as mentioned [here](https://www.sourceclear.com/vulnerability-database/security/prototype-pollution/javascript/sid-22715/). However, the above steps will work once a fix is released

Comment: This is the result

fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 1668 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated

It woudn't be fixed by above commands.

Comment: Ok, please try to delete your `package-lock.json` then try again the 2 commands I mentioned

Comment: Not solved. After two three time of attempt also I used this command "npm i --package-lock-only" to create the "package-lock.json" file again.and tried your command agind. But problem is there.

Comment: It seems like a fix to this vulnerability isn't yet released and therefore can't be fixed at this moment of time, but might be fixed in the near future. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok then. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I found some Strategy here. When I use class component for app.js file, then the this state occur. But when I use a functional component This didn't occur.

This is render Twice.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                { console.log('f')}
            </div>)
    }
}
```

This is Not render twice

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
        <div >
            {console.log("d")}
        </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the security audit result you posted.